# Add dynamic query parameter in Swagger with Fastify

Tags: javascript, parameters, swagger, swagger-ui, fastify

Is it possible to document dynamic query parameter using Fastify on Swagger, that allow client to pass the param value inside text field on Swagger UI using Swagger v1.0.0?, in my case is to input dynamic value of `conversationId` parameter.

[image]

Here is my swagger.js file in config folder.

```
exports.options = {
    routePrefix: '/documentation',
    exposeRoute: true,
    swagger: {
      info: {
        title: 'Wrapper API',
        description: 'Building a wrapper api',
        version: '1.0.0'
      },
      externalDocs: {
        url: 'https://swagger.io',
        description: 'Find more info here'
      },
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      schemes: [
        'http',
        'https'
      ], 
      consumes: ['application/json'],
      produces: ['application/json'], 
    }
  }
```

**+ Here is my route**

```
const healthBotController = require('../controllers/healthBotWrapperController')

const routes = [
  {
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    handler: healthBotController.getEndpoints
  },
]

module.exports = routes;
```

I tried to search and read document but I couldn't find solution to my problem yet. 
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: How did you have set up the route on fastify?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon route on fastify I have separate file call routes/index.js like this sir 

const healthBotController = require('../controllers/healthBotWrapperController')

const routes = [
  {
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    handler: healthBotController.getEndpoints
  },
]

module.exports = routes;

Comment: I have updated route on my question as well.

Comment: Ok, but how the swagger configuration is used? I don't see any `schema` configuration in the route, so if you are using `fastify-swagger` it will not load the parameters

Comment: So Mr. Maneul there is no way to make parameters from using fastify-swagger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the query parameters in swagger, you need to define a JSON Schema in the route configuration:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')()

fastify.register(require('fastify-swagger'), {
  routePrefix: '/documentation',
  exposeRoute: true,
  swagger: {
    info: {
      title: 'Wrapper API',
      description: 'Building a wrapper api',
      version: '1.0.0'
    },
    externalDocs: {
      url: 'https://swagger.io',
      description: 'Find more info here'
    },
    host: 'localhost:3000',
    schemes: [
      'http',
      'https'
    ],
    consumes: ['application/json'],
    produces: ['application/json'],
    securityDefinitions: {
      ApiToken: {
        description: 'Authorization header token, sample: "Bearer #TOKEN#"',
        type: 'apiKey',
        name: 'Authorization',
        in: 'header'
      },
      Oauth2Token: {
        description: 'OAUTH2',
        type: 'oauth2',
        flow: 'accessCode',
        authorizationUrl: 'https://example.com/oauth/authorize',
        tokenUrl: 'https://example.com/oauth/token',
        scopes: {
          read: 'Grants read access',
          foo: 'Grants foao scope'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

fastify.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/',
  schema: {
    security: [{ ApiToken: [], Oauth2Token: [] }],
    querystring: {
      foo: { type: 'number' },
      bar: { type: 'string' }
    }
  },
  handler: function foo () {}
})

fastify.listen(8080)
```

Then in http://localhost:8080/documentation you will see:

[image: query params]

Comment: Thank you Mr. Manuel for your answer, Could you let me know where can you find this solution, are there any document reference of this answer?

Comment: This is the [`dynamic` mode](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-swagger/#dynamic) in the docs

Comment: I see Mr. Maneul. You mentioned about the parameter, so how about putting the Authoization header like Bearer <token> since I check my Swagger is version 1.0.0. I have done it but it return [object object].

Comment: Work like charm sir. Thank you. By the way it would be great if you could provide where references to learn all of these things from starting point to be more senior level of doing with things like this with Swagger. Kind of I want to learn how to fish.